# How to fix error: Cannot find control with path: 'array-> group -> name'

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling, angular-reactive-forms, formarray

I can't bind my input. I'm using Angular Reactive forms. They have an initial value assigned.

[image: Error Image Here]

My HTML (**form** instead of **div** is the same)

```
<div [formGroup]="secondFormGroup" class="steper_ctform">

    <div class="steper_sstitle">Añadir Artículo</div>

    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="steper_artsrh">
        <mat-label>Buscar Producto</mat-label>
        <input matInput placeholder="Ej.  151FGD " class="steper_inp_as">
    </mat-form-field>
    <button (click)="addSfdynamic()">Añadir Componente</button>

    <ng-container formArrayName="articulos">
        <div *ngFor="let art of artarray.controls; let i = index">
            <ng-container [formGroupName]="i">
                <div class="sf_ctart">
                    <div [attr.for]="'art' + i">{{art.value.id}}</div>
                    <div>{{art.value.nart}}</div>
                    <input type="text" formControlName='am'>
                    <button (click)="eraseArt(i)">B</button>
                </div>
            </ng-container>

        </div>
    </ng-container>


</div>
```

This is my *ts*

```js
secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({

  articulos: this._formBuilder.array([
    {
      id:"1",
      nart: "T",
      am: 0,
    },
    {
      id:"2",
      nart: "T",
      am: 1,
    },
    {
      id:"3",
      nart: "M",
      am: 0,
    },      
  ]),

});

public get artarray(): FormArray {
  return this.secondFormGroup.get('articulos') as FormArray
}
```

I'm hard stuck, please help :)
Everything seems 'ok' to me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is the correct way to initialize values to `FormArray`.

Instead, you have to create `FormGroup` for each array element, and then add into the `FormArray`.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
    articulos: this._formBuilder.array([]),
  });

  this.setArticulosFormGroup([
    {
      id: '1',
      nart: 'T',
      am: 0,
    },
    {
      id: '2',
      nart: 'T',
      am: 1,
    },
    {
      id: '3',
      nart: 'M',
      am: 0,
    },
  ]);
}

setArticulosFormGroup(items: any[]) {
  for (let item of items) {
    let formGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      id: item.id,
      nart: item.nart,
      am: item.am,
    });

    this.artarray.push(formGroup);
  }
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5kp9nb?file=src/angular-theme.scss)

---

**References**

[Angular FormArray - Complete Guide](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-form-array/)

Comment: You were rigth it wasn't the correct way to initialize values. It worked! Thanks. Yet I need to use the get method so I can't declare my initial FormGroup in ngOnInit but It also works.